# convert string to Integer in a javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, parsing, type-conversion

I have a javascript function that takes two parameters: The first one if the ID of a given html division, and the second one is the content of a row of resultSet (returned from the DB).

```
    function displayItem(item_ID, content)
    {  
        alert(typeof(item_ID)); // this one returns a String
        el = document.getElementById(item_ID);
        alert(el);

      dispArea=document.getElementById("individual");
      dispArea.innerHTML=content; 

  }
```

The problem comes when I try to call the function in one of my links:

```
     <ul id="principle_items">
                             <!--  <%int x=0; %> !-->
                             <c:set value ="0" var="x" />
                             <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
                             <c:set value ="${x+1}" var="x" />
                            <!--  <% out.println("the value of X is " + x +"\n");%>  !-->

                             <li><a id="${x}" href="#" onclick="displayItem(this.id,'${result.rows[8].PRNCPL_NAME}');"><c:out value="${row.PRNCPL_NAME}"/></a></li>
                            </c:forEach>
         </ul>
```

instead of selecting reslut.rows[8], I want the index to be the integer value of this.id (all my IDs are "1", "2", "3"...)
         onclick="displayItem(this.id,'${result.rows[8].PRNCPL_NAME}');"

when I tried 
        onclick="displayItem(this.id,'${result.rows[this.id].PRNCPL_NAME}');" it did not work obviously because this.id is a string. I know I can use parseInt in Java, but I I am not sure how to do if here within the same statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* the issue is with parsing of JSP and JavaScript.  They are done at different times.  So you can't run JavaScript at JSP parsing time.

So your ID is just **${x}**, can you not just put x into your code like this...

```
onclick="displayItem(this.id,'${result.rows[x].PRNCPL_NAME}');"
```

Or something similar?

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseInt` function

```
alert(typeof(parseInt(item_ID)));
//should be "number"
```

**DEMO**

```js
var item_ID = "7";
alert(typeof(parseInt(item_ID)));
```

Comment: If I use it within the function call, I get the error : The function "parseInt" can not be found in the specified tag library

Comment: try `window.parseInt`

Comment: Please not : I want to convert it during the function call, not in the JS function body.

Comment: try with `window.parseInt(item_ID)` from your function body.

Comment: onclick="displayItem(this.id,'${result.rows[window.parseInt(this.id)].PRNCPL_NAME}' does not seem to work.

Comment: your answer makes perfect sense, yet, I am not sure why it did not work . I think it has to do with the difference between JS and JSP as mentioned by @Quantumplate

Comment: Thanks for te detailed answer Tareeq. The reason I don't want to handle the situation within the JS function iteself is the fact that I will not be able to access the variable '${result.rows}' with ease since it is a JSP variable  (unless of course I use a library like JQuery ); that's why I preferred to send the whole content as parameter, and let the JS function worry about displaying only. But you are right, it is not the best practive

Comment: @John Thanks for the clarification. I see you have already received the acceptable answer. I will just keep my first answer (reverse my last edit) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) as described in [Tareq Mahmood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378190/convert-string-to-integer-in-a-javascript-parameter/34378205#34378205) but the `parseInt` function also accepts a *radix* which causes values to always be calculated using that *base* preventing potential errors when reading certain numbers like `08` for instance.

From MDN:

> **radix**
>
> An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in
>   mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string. Specify
>   10 for the decimal numeral system commonly used by humans. Always
>   specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee
>   predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different
>   results when a radix is not specified, usually defaulting the value to
>   10.

Your function becomes this:

```
function displayItem(item_ID, content) {
    var item_ID = parseInt(item_ID, 10);  
    alert(typeof(item_ID)); // this one returns a String
    el = document.getElementById(item_ID);
    alert(el);

    dispArea = document.getElementById("individual");
    dispArea.innerHTML=content; 

}
```

Should you have to work with decimal numbers then there's it's brother [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) that might be able to help you out.